# Role based security in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, role-based

In my ASP.NET 3.5 application, on the ASPX pages I have to implement role based data update policy.

If a user have lest privilege, he can still update *some* filed but not all. Where user with maximum privilege can update all filed on page.

I was trying to implement this using a generic approach, but not sure if .NET have some thing inbuilt to implement this.

What is the right approach here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will want to utilize [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).  Once you have that in place, you can check roles on a user, like so:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("User1", "Role1"))
    // allow whatever you need to
```

Comment: by this I have to keep code on each and every control on all pages. I am trying to find a generic approach.

Comment: @iPhoneDev You can definitely exercise DRY by putting this in a class and having the calls go to this one class to determine what files are able to be accessed by.  This is pretty generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the asp.net [membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), you can limit the content on the page based on the roles the user is in